# Convert existing LVM LV to bcache backing device

Tags: linux, lvm, cache, block-device, bcache

How do I convert an existing LVM LV to a `bcache` backing device?

The official tool for converting an existing device to `bcache` is [`blocks`](https://github.com/g2p/blocks), but it hasn't been updated since December 2014.

At a minimum, issues [13](https://github.com/g2p/blocks/issues/13) and [36](https://github.com/g2p/blocks/issues/36) prevent it from working with maintboot and btrfs.

How can I manually convert a LVM LV to `bcache`?

Answer (score 3):

### Overview

Having looked at the source for `blocks`, what it does is:

1. Shrink the LV's filesystem is shrunk by one LVM PE
2. Shrink the LV itself by one LVM PE (this guarantees one free PE to be used for the `bcache` header)
3. Edit the VG config, insert a new first segment of size 1 being the PE that was freed in the previous step
4. Create a bcache backing device with `--data-offset` being the size of one LVM PE.

#### Gather data; shrink LV; make VG configuration backup

First get the PE size of the VG (usually 4MiB):

```
sudo vgdisplay /dev/mapper/VG | grep 'PE Size'
```

Shrink the LV's filesystem by this amount (filesystem specific). Be careful to not confuse the 4MiB with 4MB.

Then shrink the LV itself. `lvresize` uses ^2 units, so 4M=4MiB:

```
sudo lvresize -L -4M /dev/mapper/VG-LV
```

Next, find the `Start` of the newly unallocated PE:

```
sudo pvs --segments -o +lv_name,seg_start_pe,seg_size_pe,seg_pe_ranges,seg_le_ranges
```

In my (very, very ugly) allocation, the wanted `Start` column figure is `177406`:

```
  PV         VG  Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree Start  SSize  LV     Start  SSize  PE Ranges               LE Ranges
  /dev/sdb1  2TB lvm2 a--  <693.00g 4.00m      0 177406 backup 299499 177406 /dev/sdb1:0-177405      /dev/sdb1:0-177405
  /dev/sdb1  2TB lvm2 a--  <693.00g 4.00m 177406      1             0      1
  /dev/sdb2  2TB lvm2 a--  <662.96g    0       0 149749 backup 149750 149749 /dev/sdb2:0-149748      /dev/sdb2:0-149748
  /dev/sdb2  2TB lvm2 a--  <662.96g    0  149749  19968 backup 129782  19968 /dev/sdb2:149749-169716 /dev/sdb2:149749-169716
  /dev/sdb3  2TB lvm2 a--   506.96g    0       0 129782 backup      0 129782 /dev/sdb3:0-129781      /dev/sdb3:0-129781
```

Note also that `177406` is one greater than the highest `LE Ranges` number for my LV which is named `backup`.

Disable the VG as it is about to be edited:

```
sudo vgchange -an VG
```

Dump the configuration of the VG:

```
sudo vgcfgbackup --file vg-config VG
sudo chown $USER vg-config
```

At this point **make a backup** of the config.

#### Edit VG configuration; insert newly freed PE as first LE

Find the LV in the `logical_volumes` part of the config file.

Increment `segment_count` to allow for creating a new segment with the newly freed extent.

Increment all existing segments (eg old `segment1` becomes `segment2`)

Make a new first segment containing the single logical extent freed up by `lvresize`:

```
        segment1 {
            start_extent = 0
            extent_count = 1

            type = "striped"
            stripe_count = 1    # linear

            stripes = [
                "pv2", 177406
            ]
        }
```

The number `177406` is the PE freed by shrinking the LV above. Make sure that the `pv#` next to it matches the correct physical device from the `physical_volumes` part of the config file.

For segment2 onwards, increment only the `start_extent`s by 1. This accounts for the new Logical Extent we inserted in `segment1`. (Hint: Use ^A in `vi` to avoid human error)
(The last segment's `extent_count` is already correct as the backup was taken after the LV was shrunken).

You can see the patch of my VG configuration [here](https://pastebin.com/NUFjuKxd).

#### Check the new VG configuration

Write the new configuration to the VG metadata:

```
sudo vgcfgrestore --file vg-config
```

Re-enable the VG:

```
sudo vgchange -ay VG
```

Loopback mount the LV with a single PE offset to check that nothing got screwed up:

```
sudo losetup --find --show --offset 4M --read-only /dev/mapper/VG-LV
```

(above we use the example PE size of 4MiB)

`fsck` **all** filesystems in the VG to check that nothing got screwed up in the segment mapping.

See rollback section (below) if something went wrong. Else, `sudo losetup --detach /dev/loop#`

#### Write `bcache` header

Make the `bcache` device with appropriate block size and data offset to match one LVM PE:

Get the data offset in sectors:

```
sudo vgdisplay --units s 2TB | grep 'PE Size'
```

For a usual 4MiB PE size, this will be 8192.

Write the bcache 8KiB header:

```
dev=/dev/mapper/VG-LV
make-bcache --bdev --data-offset 8192 --block "$(blockdev --getpbsz "$dev")" "$dev" # --writeback --cset-uuid # see `make-bcache --help`
```

Attach the newly setup backing device to a cache device.

`fsck` only the LV's filesystem (the other VG filesystems haven't been changed since last `fsck`)

Be proud that `fsck` takes only a fraction of the previous running time :)

#### Rollback

If `fsck` complains and you can't work out what you did wrong in the VG configuration file, you can just restore the backup that you took:

```
sudo vgcfgrestore -f vg-config.orig
```

Comment: Fantastic guide!  So handy for those of us too lazy to backup and restore. :)

Comment: @pauldoo glad it helped.  Any improvements, let me know.